# If I'm creating completely custom getter and setter methods do I still need an @property declaration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, getter-setter

So I want to have a "property" on a class but I don't want to just hold that property in memory, I want to actually store it as an NSUserDefault and retrieve it when you get that property.

So as such I have methods like this:

```
- (void)setUser:(User *)user {
    // actually set the user as an NSUserDefault here
}

- (User *)user {
    // get the user from the NSUserDefaults and return it
}
```

As I'm building these methods to do the work for me is there any point in having an `@property` declaration in the header file?

I'm getting mixed messages. Some people say that you should declare the property to force people to use the getter/setter methods, but I can't see why people wouldn't be forced to use those methods if they're all that are available?

Just looking for a bit of clarification.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you explicitly override the getter and setter like that, there's no point unless you want a public interface.

Comment: What do you mean by a public interface? If I define the methods in the header interface then they'll still be public surely?

Comment: a getter/setter method without property make no sense

Comment: Yes.  What I meant is that if you wanted the getter and setter to remain internal entities, then there would be very little point in a property declaration.  If, however, you want a public-interface (like you said you do), then it's cleaner to have one property than two interaction methods in the header.  It also makes CLANG and LLDB complain less about dot-syntax access on benign getters.

Comment: @peko getters and setters without an explicit property declaration make perfectly sense. Personally, I prefer to make the intent explicit through a property declaration, but both dot syntax and KVC/KVO work perfectly fine without the property declaration.

Comment: Ah thank guys. That makes sense. So @property and defining two getter/setter methods is basically the same thing, but one says that you're actually creating a property, the other makes it look like they're just two benign methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `@property` because that's the modern way to define properties on Objective-C objects, even if you implement the setter and getter yourself.

Rather than relying on convention you are making your intentions much clearer to the compiler. You will also get better syntax highlighting when using dot-notation in the IDE (although that's arguably an Xcode bug).